# .map not accessible from HttpClient

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, httpclient, angular-services

I'm following a tutorial, but it's a little outdated so I'm trying to fill in the pieces. Currently the services looks like

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';


export class TodoService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  add(todo) {
    return this.http.post('...', todo).map(r => r.json());
  }

  getTodos() {
    return this.http.get('...').map(r => r.json());
  }

  delete(id) {
    return this.http.delete('...').map(r => r.json());
  }
}
```

but it says `Cannot find module '@angular/http' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)`

So I changed it to

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
```

but now I get .map red underline with `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.ts(2339)`

I tried `import { map } from "rxjs/operators";` and `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';` but I still get error.

How can I configure this to work without rewriting this.http.post/get/delete line?

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

map is an rxjs operator, you can use it like this:

```
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
return this.http.post('...', todo).pipe(
 map(r => r.json())
);
```

and whu you are using the deprecated angular/http, you can use HttpClient

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! It's not fully working yet though. With your change I'm getting an error now on ```.json``` https://postimg.cc/t15C2n5L Any ideas?

Comment: i think there is not need to parse it to json, if you are using httpClient, so delete .json, just return the response

Comment: The .json is part of the .map so if I remove that then doesn't it defeat the purpose of having .map? Wouldn't that only leave ```return this.http.post('...', todo)``` left?

Comment: The only issue with that is that the component is mapping the response so I would get an error if I remove .map so if getTodos is like so ```getTodos() {
    return this.http.get('...');
  }``` then the component that subscribes to it https://postimg.cc/WtgVpkRg

Comment: try to define the returned data type  getTodos(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>('...');
  }

Comment: You're a rockstar! Thanks so much!